# Remove space between these items

Tags: html, css

I have included an example piece of code for an issue I'm trying to solve.  I need to remove the line of empty space between the "Serves:" and "4" background objects so they are completely adjacent to one another.  I found a suggestion to remove the space between the `<p>` tags which does work but is less than ideal for readability.

So if I do this it works:

```
<p class="serves-label">Serves:</p><p class="serves-number">4</p>
```

Is there any way to logically remove that space between the paragraph tags while still allowing them to be on their own line?

```css
.serves-container {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.serves-label,
.serves-number {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}

.serves-label {
    background-color: #1e2827;
    color: #92ab8b;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-block-end: 0;
    margin-block-start: 0;
}

.serves-number {
    background-color: #ffed58;
    color: #1d1f2c;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-block-start: 0;
    margin-block-end: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="serves-container">
  <p class="serves-label">Serves:</p>
  <p class="serves-number">4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Convert the elements to a block with `display: block`, or use HTML comments between the elements to remove the newline, because now they are `inline-block`, so they behave like a text character.

Comment: If you reopen it, I will post this as answer. Thanks.